# Get Graph Drive Id from SharePoint library name

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, flow

I'm trying to use some graph endpoints in a Flow to access a file in a library that isn't the default Documents library. I need to get the graph id for a file. All I'm starting with are the obvious things about the file, site, library name, filename, path to file, etc.

In order to get the file id I found I need to send a request to `{sharepoint-site}/_api/v2.0/drives/{drive-id}/root:/{filename}`. I have the filename, but I don't have the drive id.

All the tutorial and documentation I'm finding say something along the lines of "...`/drive` accesses the site's Documents library, if you want to access a different library you will need to use `/drives/{drive-id}`..." or "...once you have the drive id, then you use this endpoint..."

I can do something like `{site}_api/v2.0/drives?$select=id,name` which will return all the document libraries in the site and then iterate through those looking for the name or path of the library. But that seems like a lot of extra work.

I tried to append a `&$filter=name eq '{library-name]'` but that didn't make a difference it just listed all the libraries.

Is there really no way just to get just the drive id for one library? How do I get the drive id based on the path/name of a library?

Answer (score 0):

Only the `$select` query parameter is supported for `/drives` endpoint.

`$filter` is not supported and would be ignored, as documented here: [Get Drive - Optional query parameters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters).